# Konsole not getting the full url when is a port (:) on it (on click)

Tags: linux, fish, konsole

Normally I use to do something like this when using `express` applications(Or any other type of application that involves a URL):

```js
app.listen(7070, () => console.log('Server started at port http://127.0.0.1:7070')
```

But when I click on the URL my browser opens `https://127.0.0.1` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:7070`. I remember that this was not the way it used to work, but not entirely sure.

I am using `Konsole(v22.04.1)` over `fish(v.3.4.1)` (Fish does not seem important, as it is reproducible with bash and not with `alacritty`).

[image: Sample Image]

As you can see, the `:` prevents the entire URL from being selected. Does anyone know of a way to change this behavior, and have the entire URL selected?

Comment: What behavior do you see if you just `Server started at port http://127.0.0.1:7070'` from the shell?  On 21.12.3 that works for me (takes the entire URI including the port).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, thanks for taking a look into this. The behavior is the described in the post, when I `Ctrl` + click on it, I get redirected to `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1`, totally ignoring the port. I am in an Arch Machine (KDE Desktop with X11), if that change anything.

Comment: Oops - Rereading my comment, I had a bad copy/paste.  It should have been `echo "Server started at port http://127.0.0.1:7070"`.  That said, I figured it was Arch (or some other rolling release) given the recent Konsole version.  I should have tested there first, and I'd have reproduced it earlier.  Still, it was useful to figure out that it works under Ubuntu with an earlier release.  That pointed to a likely regression in Konsole, which turns out to be the case.

Comment: The fix https://invent.kde.org/utilities/konsole/-/merge_requests/646

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a [known issue](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=452978) with 22.04.

I was able to reproduce on Arch (using Windows Subsystem for Linux) with 22.04.01, but it works fine on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (also under WSL) which currently uses Konsole 21.12.3.